# Geometry Nodes Points (and instances) not showing in a small sized objects

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles, point-clouds

I'm working in a really small sized object with real scale size (about 13 mm length object) and I make a distribution node tree to put some tiny rocks distributed in part of the model. All transforms applied in all objects. I try to append a nodetree that have been using in bigger objects and it doesn't work. When I try to recreate it I see the node "Ditribute points on faces" is not showing any point.
After a lot of testing, I find "Ditribute points on faces" shows points and particles when I put some negative value in Density Max value (multiplying the input value by -1). That makes the points appear, but no matter which negative value I put, the density always remains the same.
Do someone know if this is normal, or just a bug, or how can I do the trick to get the particles (hair particles like distribution on the object) but avoiding particles overlapping, controlling the density of the particles and the depth the particles go through the surface?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/